# Al arrancar Spring Boot, aparece "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vscode, spring-tool-suite

a la hora de arrancar mi proyecto de **spring** en **vscode** me dice lo siguiente:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _

 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \

( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \

 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )

  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /

 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/

 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)



2019-05-28 11:58:26.250  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.crn.tienda.demo.DemoApplication      : Starting DemoApplication on DESKTOP-REPNVGL with PID 12564 (C:\Users\Josel\Desktop\TIENDA-SPRING-ANGULAR\BACKEND\tienda\demo\target\classes started by Josel in C:\Users\Josel\Desktop\TIENDA-SPRING-ANGULAR\BACKEND\tienda\demo)

2019-05-28 11:58:26.253  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.crn.tienda.demo.DemoApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default

2019-05-28 11:58:26.320  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable

2019-05-28 11:58:26.320  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'

2019-05-28 11:58:27.197  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.

2019-05-28 11:58:27.277  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.

2019-05-28 11:58:27.677  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4dc17a39] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

2019-05-28 11:58:28.067  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)

2019-05-28 11:58:28.098  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]

2019-05-28 11:58:28.098  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]

2019-05-28 11:58:28.296  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext

2019-05-28 11:58:28.296  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1975 ms

2019-05-28 11:58:28.486  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...

2019-05-28 11:58:28.670  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

2019-05-28 11:58:28.724  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [

    name: default

    ...]

2019-05-28 11:58:28.817  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}

2019-05-28 11:58:28.819  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

2019-05-28 11:58:29.005  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}

2019-05-28 11:58:29.168  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect

2019-05-28 11:58:29.343  WARN 12564 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario

2019-05-28 11:58:29.344  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...

2019-05-28 11:58:29.352  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

2019-05-28 11:58:29.356  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]

2019-05-28 11:58:29.367  INFO 12564 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 



Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.

2019-05-28 11:58:29.373 ERROR 12564 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed



org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
```

Mi **application.properties** es :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_tienda?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug

server.port=8080
```

Mi **entity** es **Usuario.java**

```
package com.crn.tienda.demo.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

/**
 * Usuario
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "usuarios")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "nombre")
    private String nombre;

    @Column(name = "apellidos")
    private String apellidos;

    @Column(name = "usuario")
    private String usuario;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "passsword")
    private String passsword;

    @Column(name = "fecha_registro")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createAt;

    /**
     * @return Long return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the apellidos
     */
    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @param apellidos the apellidos to set
     */
    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the usuario
     */
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @param usuario the usuario to set
     */
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * @param email the email to set
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * @return String return the passsword
     */
    public String getPasssword() {
        return passsword;
    }

    /**
     * @param passsword the passsword to set
     */
    public void setPasssword(String passsword) {
        this.passsword = passsword;
    }

    /**
     * @return Date return the createAt
     */
    public Date getCreateAt() {
        return createAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param createAt the createAt to set
     */
    public void setCreateAt(Date createAt) {
        this.createAt = createAt;
    }

}
```

**UsuarioDao.java**

```
    package com.crn.tienda.demo.dao;

    import com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario;

    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
    import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

    /**
     * IUsuarioDao
     */
    public interface IUsuarioDao extends CrudRepository<Usuario,Long> {

        @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.email = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
        Usuario findByEmailandPassword(String email, String password);

        @Query("select u from Usuario u where u.usuario = ?1 and u.password = ?2")
        Usuario findByUserandPassword(String usuario, String password);

    }
```

**IUsuarioService.java**

```
package com.crn.tienda.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario;

/**
 * IUsuarioService
 */
public interface IUsuarioService {

    public List<Usuario> findAll();

}
```

**UsuarioServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.crn.tienda.demo.services;

import java.util.List;

import com.crn.tienda.demo.dao.IUsuarioDao;
import com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

/**
 * UsuarioServiceImpl
 */
@Service
public class UsuarioServiceImpl implements IUsuarioService {

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioDao usuarioDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Usuario> findAll() {
        return (List<Usuario>) usuarioDao.findAll();
    }

}
```

**Clase main**

```
package com.crn.tienda.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Pero cuál es tu pregunta? y una cosa que no he podido evitar notar en varias preguntas que has hecho, deberías desacoplar lo que es spring de lo que es el ide/editor vscode en tu caso. Quiero decir, tu podrías arrancar el proyecto desde un terminal perfectamente, tu pregunta está relacionada únicamente con spring y poner vscode es redundante para la pregunta y puede atraer a que la gente piense que el problema lo tienes con el ide, un saludo!!!!!

Comment: Buenas, es que el problema seguramente sea del IDE, por eso pongo VSCODE, se que si lo hago con eclipse va a funcionar. Por eso pongo VSCODE y spring , porque al juntar ambos es cuando me peta., un saludo!

Comment: no tiene nada de sentido lo que estás diciendo, tienes un problema de hibernate. La excepción dice claramente : No identifier specified for entity: ... que es bastante explicativo de que te falta un id en alguna identidad o alguna configuración del datasource que impide que detecte el id si si lo tienes puesto. el IDE no es más que un lector de tu proyecto, tu proyecto JAMÁS puede fallar debido a configuraciones del ide, el ide te da herramientas para levantar el proyecto o configurar ciertos parámetros pero si el proyecto no compila como en tu caso es porque hay algo mal en el mismo...

Comment: Lo del @Id en principio no deberia de ser. A mi se me vienen 2 posibles errores. Que no detecte la identidad debido a donde esta el package que la contiene. O problemas con alguna configuracion de application.properties. Me gustaria que le echaras un vistazo al fichero de app.properties por si vieses algo extraño y si los packages de las clases son correctos, me explico con esto ultimo. Me dijistes en otra pregunta que igual no alcanzaba a leer el main las demas clases, asi que yo las puse dentrodel paquete main.
Y esas son mis dos sospechas de porque no funcionan

Comment: cambia el import de tu id por import javax.persistence.Id y dime si te funciona

Comment: Si eso era, ya me di cuenta al abrir el proyecto con eclipse. Vaya tonteria de verdad. Muchas gracias.

Comment: te he generado una respuesta acorde por si la consideras válida, un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.crn.tienda.demo.entity.Usuario
```

este error implica que hibernate no encuentra el id que has puesto en tu entidad porque no estás usando el import adecuado, el id de base de datos corresponde al import:

```
 javax.persistence.Id
```

Como otra recomendación, en tu repositorio te recomiendo extender de jpaRepository en lugar de crudRepository. Puedes ver las diferencias aquí: [jpaRepository vs crudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014086/what-is-difference-between-crudrepository-and-jparepository-interfaces-in-spring)

pero como descripción por encima, jpaRepository ya incorpora el crudRepository pero añade herramientas de paginación y persistencia varias.